# Calling clojure function from java but unable to find classpath

Tags: java, clojure

I am trying to call a clojure function from a java class but even though the clojure file is located at the same place as the java class, its throwing

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not
>   locate com/foo/names__init.class or
>   com/foo/names.clj on classpath.

This is my project structure:

```
src
  main
    java
      com
        foo
          names.clj
          TestClj.java
```

names.clj

```
(ns com.foo.names) 
(defn add-me
  [one two]
   (+ one two))
```

TestClj.java

```
public class TestClj {
  private static final IFn REQUIRE = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require");

  public TestClj(String ns) {
        this.ns = ns;
        REQUIRE.invoke(Clojure.read(ns));  <- Breaks here
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClj clj = new TestClj("com.foo.names");
        Clojure.var("com.foo.names", "add-me").invoke(1, 2);
  }  
}
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT** Adding the pom file

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
                <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0-alpha5</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
            <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>clojars.org</id>
            <name>Clojars repository</name>
            <url>https://clojars.org/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: How is your project being built? Java sources aren't typically put onto the classpath, they're compiled to some temporary location which is added to the classpath.

Comment: @Alex I have added my pom structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Maven to build a Java project, with a little bit of Clojure sprinkled in alongside. This should work, but will require a slightly different layout than what you currently have. As indicated in the exception message, Clojure's compiler expects to find the source code for namespace `com.foo.names` as a resource on the classpath at `com/foo/names.clj`.

In the [Maven standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)  `src/main/java` is where *source files* go, and is not added to the project's classpath. For resource files that you do want on the classpath, you want `src/main/resources`:

> Within artifact producing source directories (ie. main and test), there is one directory for the language java (under which the normal package hierarchy exists), and one for resources (the structure which is copied to the target classpath given the default resource definition).

Try putting the Clojure file at `src/main/resources/com/foo/names.clj`. This should fix the immediate cause of your exception.

If, as indicated in the comments, you want your project's Clojure code to be treated as source code in its own right, then take a look at the [Clojure Maven plugin](https://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin). This should allow you to put Clojure source code under `src/main/clojure` and have it compiled alongside the Java code, with the compiled Clojure code available on the classpath.

If your project is primarily in Clojure, the most common build framework in the Clojure ecosystem is [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/), which you might also want to take a look at.

Comment: That does make sense and it works but if that's the way to do it then I don't think I can use clojure here cause the clojure file will contain business logic functions which java would call. So it should not be in the resources folder. Is there a way convince maven that there are two different language folders?

Comment: @noMAD See edits - it sounds like you want the Clojure Maven plugin.